# Angular JS ngView performance in IE

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, internet-explorer

Brief background:  We're working on converting an application to use AngularJS.  Instead of rewriting wholesale every page, I'm using Angular's ngView and passing a PHP file as the templateUrl.

In chrome/firefox/safari.  This is fast, but in IE, this operation seems to take an inordinate amount of time.  IE seems to dawdle during innerHtml operations.  On pages that are fully Angularized, even pages with huge sets of ng-repeat data, this seems to move rather quickly.

I'm wondering if there is some sort of performance hit when I insert large blocks of HTML into the ng-view vs inserting smaller blocks of text, as with data binding, or if anyone knows of any magic-bullet fixes that can improve the performance of these operations.  On IE, an entire page reload with four or five times more actual data being transferred are faster than the population of the view with just the changed data.